# How to use Firebase DebugView for App Tracking

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-analytics, debugview

I need to debug the tracking events and parameters for an app, but as I am a marketer I do not have access to the project or any skills in development. However, I have the DEV version of the APK and managed to open it in Android Studio and connect my Android device through adb to see something in logcat.

Unfortunately, this does not help as I actually was hoping to see data in the DebugView of Firebase (or GA4), but both tools still tell me that "No Device found".

I walked through this article https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview, but the situation remains the same.

Can somebody help me how to see app interactions in the DebugView. I appreciate any help on the requirements and setup of my testing environment.

Best regards,
Manuel

Answer (score 1):

**note : install adb if you don't have it installed on system.**

Its very easy to use just open up a terminal or command window & add this with your device connected to system.

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.app
```

that's it now you can open up your app & debug view will show your device with all the events etc, after you're done simple use this command to stop the debugView

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.
```